# Meaning of "Midoriya leans over the railing—so far—so far that the world cannot follow if and where he falls."

Tags: meaning

Midoriya leans over the railing—so far—so far that the world cannot follow if and where he falls. He stretches his scarred arms out, baring himself to a fierce wind that pushes the hair from his forehead. The setting sun stains his skin gold, and he is not unlike a child, and then he is nothing like one.

I can’t understand the first sentence

Comment: This looks like fantasy writing. Is it? Writers, even professional writers, sometimes take some poetic license in their writing. Don't get caught up in close reading. Here, the first sentence simply means that Midoroya is leaning dangerously far over the rail. The implication is recklessness or perhaps boldness. Hard to tell from the quoted passage. The author is using a weird image to convey that implication; the language doesn't really mean anything intelligible.

Comment: This may be better suited for our [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) site. Textual analysis is welcomed there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is quite straight-forward, it merely uses dashes to divide the sentence into three parts, with each new part commenting on the previous one:

- He leans over the rail.
- An expression showing that he leans much further than one would expect.
- An imaginative scenario where, if he did fall, it would be beyond anywhere we could reasonably expect.

We could compare the sentence with this structure: far, farther, farthest